# Async Function returning Undefined when calling it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I'm Having some trouble with this function on a React project

```
let fetchData = async (event, imagen) => {
    const apiURL = `https://some_api_call/${imagen}`;
    await axios.get(apiURL).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data.Imagen1.data);
      return response.data.Imagen1.data;
    });
```

When i call it the Console.log returns Undefined but the console log above returns the data

```
fetchData(event, rowData.Codigo).then(function (response) {
console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: You need to return the awaited axios call in the function.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, do you mean like " return await axios.get..."?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: that indeed would return the promise and then you can use the `.then` or you can even `let response=await fetchData(...args)`

Comment: Thank you both for the answer it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let fetchData = async (event, imagen) => {
    const apiURL = `https://some_api_call/${imagen}`;
    return await axios.get(apiURL);
}
fetchData(event, rowData.Codigo).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: ok i had a small syntax error.. it's fixed now

Answer (score 1):

Your `fetchData` function has no `return` statement. You probably don't want to use `then` when there is `await`:

```
async function fetchData(event, imagen) {
  const apiURL = `https://some_api_call/${imagen}`;
  const response = await axios.get(apiURL)
  console.log(response.data.Imagen1.data);
  return response.data.Imagen1.data;
}
```